# Why can a nullable value still be considered nullable inside the scope of an if statement that checks for nullability?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

Consider this demo:

```
void test(int? n) {
  if (n != null) { // let's make sure n is not null
    ++n; // ok; n is assumed to be non-null

    if (n < 0) {
      n = n.abs(); // ok; n is not null in inner scope
    }

    while (n != 0) {
      --n; // error: the method '-' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'
    }
  }
}
```

Why is `n` still considered `int?` inside the `while(...) { ... }` block? I am using VSCode with the latest version of Dart.

Comment: See https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1308.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike the code earlier in your method body, the code in your `while` loop can be run multiple times. It's possible for you to assign `null` to `n` in one of your loop's iterations and, therefore, be possible to call `--` on a `null` object.

Dart's static analysis is able to see that `n` will not be null with non-looping code relatively easily, it just has to go through each line to see if there is a possible `null` assignment. With the loop, Dart's analysis is just not that smart. I'm guessing this detection cannot be done as it would require actually running your loop's code to determine if `n` could become `null` again.

The following loop shows an example of where automatic `n` cannot be guaranteed to be `null`, even though `n` is not assigned to be `null` prior to `--n`:

```dart
while (n != 0) {
  --n; // error: the method '-' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'
  if(n == 5) {
    n = null;
  }
}
```

In order to determine if `n` can be `null` at the `--n`, Dart's analysis would have *look ahead* to see that `n` is assigned to `null`.

---

Cases like this where Dart's analysis is not able to accurately determine if a variable could be `null` is why the bang operator exists:

```dart
void test(int? n) {
  if (n != null) { // let's make sure n is not null
    ++n; // ok; n is assumed to be non-null

    if (n < 0) {
      n = n.abs(); // ok; n is not null in inner scope
    }

    while (n != 0) {
      n = n! - 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a local non-nullable variable for your particular example:

```dart
void test(int? n) {
  if (n != null) { // let's make sure n is not null
    int nLocal = n;
    ++nLocal; // ok; n is assumed to be non-null

    if (n < 0) {
      nLocal = nLocal.abs(); // ok; n is not null in inner scope
    }

    while (n != 0) {
      --nLocal;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The bang operator `--!n;` does not compile for me. Error: `Missing selector such as '.identifier' or '[0]'.
Try adding a selector.`. However, I can do `n = n! - 1`. What am I missing?

Comment: @offworldwelcome I thought I tested that syntax in dartpad when I wrote this answer, but you're not missing anything. It's not valid. This syntax is proposed however: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/53f3e4606f7efe25679c37698e167734df7f934c/working/1113%20-%20null-asserting%20compound%20assignment/proposal.md. I'll edit my answer to be more accurate.

Comment: Thank you, your comment was very clear. I had a for loop earlier in the code (before the null check) to set the variable, and that is why i needed to add a bang operator after the null check. I think it's an error that should be fixed in the upcoming versions of Dart